# glew build $PATH issue

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to build glew2.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 using [these instructions](http://glew.sourceforge.net/build.html).  My first error suggests PATH is setup incorrectly, regardless of what $SYSTEM is set as.

```
$ export GLEW_DEST=/usr
$ export SYSTEM=linux
$ make all
cc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_BUILD -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fPIC -Wcast-qual -ansi -pedantic -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o -c src/glew.c
In file included from src/glew.c:55:
include/GL/glxew.h:98:22: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, Xlib.h is in /usr/include/X11/.  And PATH includes both /usr and /usr/include.

```
$ echo $PATH 
/usr:/usr/include
/usr$ find -name Xlib.h 
./include/X11/Xlib.h
```

It's my understanding that gcc will attempt to locate files in the directories in PATH.  I briefly browsed Makefile and the corresponding Makefile.linux in the config directory to see if anything weird is going on here (like overwriting PATH).  I would prefer not to modify the source as that can be long, daunting rabbit hole in itself.

Also, I have verified all the header files have read permissions for all users.

Is there something I'm forgetting?

Comment: *"It's my understanding that gcc will attempt to locate files in the directories in PATH"* - no, see [What are the GCC default include directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories)

Answer (score 0):

Ask the packaging system!

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h
libx11-dev:amd64: /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

and install the `libx11-dev` package.